# Could not find or load main class main using Android Studio

Tags: java, command-line-interface

I'm working on learning how to code games in Java. Since Android studio isn't supporting eclipse it just made sense to use the IDE I'm already using to write my Java programs. I had to do some digging but I figured out how to make that work.

My issue is that I can run the programs while in the IDE but when I try to run the program from the command line, even something as simple as "Hello, World" I get this error.

Could not find or load main class main

Now this odd because the director contains both a main.class and a main.java plus the program does compile and run when run from android studio itself. I would like to be able to resolve this to run my programs at the command line.

Comment: which command did you use to run your program?

Comment: I used javac main.java 
followed by
java main